# Cannot add SVG element to DOM

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to make a canvas and `<svg>` element inside a `<div>`, but it does not show up, even in the element inspector.

**HTML**

```
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="top-container">
                <div class="title"></div>
                <div class="source"></div>
                <div class="logo"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="middle-container">
                <div class="tooltip-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-container"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**Javascript**

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var width = 454;
var height = 400;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select(".bottom-container")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 454)
    .attr("height", 465)
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx",25)
    .attr("cy",25)
    .attr("r",25)
    .style("fill", "purple");
```

When I change the `d3.select(".bottom-container")` to `d3.select(".any-class")` it is not working, but when I change it to `d3.select("body")` it worked—the `<svg>` and the `<circle>` elements show up in both browser and element inspector.

Comment: Also related, no duplicate, though: [*jquery .ready() equivalent in d3js?*](/q/34469877).